# Access Import Wizard Large Number column

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to import a file with order numbers that have values in excess of 9 billion into Access.

I have already figured out that I needed to switch from Access 2013 to Access 2016 so that I could enable "Support Bigint Data Type for Linked/Imported Tables". This enabled the Large Number data type in the Access Database.

At this point, I can manually enter Large Numbers into Access, and everything works okay, but when I try to import a .csv with Large Numbers, I get data conversion errors for the Large Numbers (and only the Large Numbers).

In the past, I encountered the issue where text columns starting with what appeared to be a number in the first row encountered conversion errors for actual text values, so I tried putting the Large Number order numbers on the top of the file, and that didn't work.

Can anyone confirm that the Access 2016 Import Wizard can't import Large Number values?

If not, has anyone successfully used import wizard to get a Large Number into Access? How did you achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use a 20 year old version of access and it can handle numbers with 28 digits.

And if you can enter such numbers manually, the the data is messed up, has extra junk, or extra characters. So no, upgrading will not by magic fix bad formatted data.

I would consider perhaps importing the data, and using say a text column for that data, and then perhaps then see if you can remove junk.

but, if you want to try a larger column, then try currency. and if you want REALLY HUGE WHOPPER then you can use this:

[image]

As you can see in above, that is 18 digits long!!!!

So, if the import is failing with above, then attempting to use a MUCH smaller big int will not help you at all here - not at all.

So, try above - see if that works.

However, the fact that you can type in the larger values by hand means that the issue here is messy data - and not that the numbers are too large.

You may well have to settle for importing that column as text, and then running some update query, or even some VBA code to clean out or clear out bad junk and characters or even perhaps extra spaces etc.

So, you don't need to change access to get and allow you to work with larger numbers. The "main" goal and idea behind that larger number is really for better SQL server support, and it not really much if at all a new feature designed to allow you to work with larger numbers (that's more of a by-product of the first goal).

Comment: Intriguing theory, but I just made a simple .txt file with a column header and the number "98789123584". I tried importing it into a new table, I tried importing into an existing Large Number table, and on your suggestion, I tried importing into a Number (Decimal, 18) table, and all three errored out citing a data conversion error. So it doesnt seem as though your explanation is accurate, and I still cant get the data through the importer.

Comment: For good measure, I just tried to change the column to text and import the number. Data conversion error. I would imagine that is because the import wizard is identifying the value as numerical, but as it goes to convert numerical to string, the value is over 3 billion so it throws an error... so ya. Still without a workaround to get Access import wizard to take in a number larger than 3 billion.

Comment: Try using currency data type. It will go up to about 15 digits. If that can't work, then a big int will also not work. Then, just import that column as a string  - you have to do house cleaning on that data. But, currency data type will support rather large numbers. If currency data import fails, then a big int input will also fail. As noted, then you have to import that column as text. Find the offending data, and then send the data over to a currency data type, or a decimal type, or a big int type if you upgrade. However, if currency data type fails, then the problem is not number size.

Answer (score 0):

I think people are safer importing using a text file.  Access' import specification just seems to fail. I can't rely on it for production systems - the comment by James Marshall above is correct.  you can tell Access to import as text, but before it does, if it sees a phone number, say, it will try to convert to a long int first and then just not import numbers exceeding memory, like phone numbers with area codes > 212